# Solr to query the last index of array

Tags: solr, websphere-commerce

Query the last index field in Solr Array.

Below is the solr document for one product has the parentCatgroup_id_search as the attribute field

```
<arr name="parentCatgroup_id_search">
<str>10001_14533</str>
<str>10001_14501</str>
<str>10001_14502</str>
<str>20051_15060</str>
<str>20051_15096</str>
<str>20051_15121</str>
<str>20051_15144</str>
</arr>
```

is there any way to query all the documents matches '20051_15144' as the last index of parentCatgroup_id_search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no built-in support for querying a specific index in a multi valued field.

If this is a specific requirement for your application, you should index the last value as a separate field - i.e. `parentCatgroup_id_search_last`. If you need to search by index, as well as `last` or `first`, create a second field where you prefix the values with their indices and any aliases you need - for example `last:20051_15144`.