# Solr filter query on last element of array of object

Tags: rest, filter, solr

I have a solr collection containing a field which is array of objects like this -

```
[
    {
        "id":"a1",
        "stages":[
            {
                "work":"collect",
                "status":"PENDING"
            },
            {
                "work":"operate",
                "status":"RUNNING"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"a2",
        "stages":[
            {
                "work":"collect",
                "status":"PENDING"
            },
            {
                "work":"regular",
                "status":"RUNNING"
            },
            {
                "work":"post",
                "status":"CLOSED"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"a3",
        "stages":[
            {
                "work":"collect",
                "status":"PENDING"
            },
            {
                "work":"regular",
                "status":"RUNNING"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"a4",
        "stages":[
            {
                "work":"collect",
                "status":"PENDING"
            },
            {
                "work":"regular",
                "status":"CANCELLED"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here, `stages` is an array of objects where each object has two fields - `work` and `status`. I want to filter out the records which does not have `status` as `CLOSED` OR `CANCELLED`. So, in above example records with ids - `a1` & `a3` will be in the output.

I have tried to use filter query in my rest call as follows -

```
"fq":["-status.status:CLOSED OR CANCELLED"]
```

But it's not working and outputs 400 response code. The `CLOSED` and `CANCELLED` status will be at the last index of the array. Is there any way to query only the last index ?
According to this question, it isn't feasible to query specific index of array in solr -
[Solr to query the last index of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041825/solr-to-query-the-last-index-of-array)
But can we apply filter on whole array to see if any `status` contains `CLOSED` or `CANCELLED` ? That would work too.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `fq` is purely negative, so it'd probably have to be `fq=*:* -status.status:(CLOSED OR CANCELLED)` - but the Solr log should ahve the proper error for why a 400 error was generated. Also - if this is what you're going to query for often, index the last state as a separate field instead. (`{id: 2, last_status: "CLOSED", ...}`) instead. That will handle cases that have been re-opened as well.

Comment: There's also an update processor made for just this task if you want to implement it on the solr side. Not sure how/if it works with random JSON: https://solr.apache.org/docs/8_8_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/LastFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory.html